# Invalid JSON format

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm building JSON object and passing it to server with JQuery ajax.

```
data: "{'authorID' : '" + authorID +
      "', 'title' : '" + encodeURIComponent(blogTitle) +
      "', 'msg' : '" + encodeURIComponent(blogBody) +
      "', 'preview' : '" + encodeURIComponent(mediaContent) +
      "', 'layoutID' : '" + previewLayoutId +
      "', 'threadID' : '" + threadID + "'}"
```

But when my blogBody variable contains `'` the code fails with the error message:

```
{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (107): {\u0027authorID\u0027 : \u0027148385\u0027, \u0027title\u0027 : \u0027123213\u0027, \u0027msg\u0027 : \u0027%3Cp%3Eqqq%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E%3Cbr%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cp%3E\u0027\u0027\u0027\u0027%3C%2Fp%3E\u0027, \u0027preview\u0027 : \u0027\u0027, \u0027layoutID\u0027 : \u00271\u0027, \u0027threadID\u0027 : \u00270\u0027}","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

Could someone say where is the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried http://jslint.com or http://jshint.com ? Those are both good for looking at your JSON output to handle issues.

Comment: Why build the JSON by hand instead of just making a struct with the data in and serializing it?

Comment: as per the http://jsonlint.com/ your json is perfect error may coming due to your server side code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [JSON](http://json.org/), the keys must be quoted with double quotes (`"`), not single quotes (`'`). Similarly, string values must be in double, not single, quotes. You're using single quotes. For example, around `authorId` and around the text of the title.

So at a minimum, you need to swap those quotes around, e.g.:

```
data: '{"authorID" : "' + authorID +
      '", "title" : "' + encodeURIComponent(blogTitle) +
      '", "msg" : "' + encodeURIComponent(blogBody) +
      '", "preview" : "' + encodeURIComponent(mediaContent) +
      '", "layoutID" : "' + previewLayoutId +
      '", "threadID" : "' + threadID + '"}'
```

Comment: Also, you should never compose JSON yourself when there's are already [a perfectly good function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)  just lying around.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using Microsoft's `JavaScriptSerializer()` function for turning objects into JSON.

It would convert apostrophes to `\u0027`, but **jqGrid** would happily continue to display them as `\u0027`:

[image]

My solution was simply to stop using Microsoft's `JavaScriptSerializer()` function..

```
string JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(myListOfObjects).ToString();
```

..and switch to JSON.Net..

```
string JSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myListOfObjects);
```

JSON.Net also avoids the issues with converting DateTimes to JSON.  Microsoft's version uses it's own nasty formatting for dates, eg:

```
/Date(1355496152000)/
```

Errr, yeah.  Time to get Googling again.  Or use JSON.Net !

Answer (score -1):

JSON field names should be in double quotes also string values should be double quotes too. See JSON syntax rules [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp). 
Also you can validate JSON output by using an online JSON validation websites like [DebugJSON](http://debugjson.com).

Answer (score -2):

As T.J. Crowder said, your elements should have double quotes, and to make sure your format is correct, you can always validate your json array here (I always do):

Also you better use [this](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to generate the json arrays

http://jsonlint.com/