# Json - Argument exception error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, serialization

I want to add to the database with json data. Where there is error help me please.

```
$.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "bultenOku.aspx/bultenKayit",
                data: "{macBahsi:'" + macBahsi + "',ilkYariBahsi:'" + ilkYariBahsi + "',ikinciYariBahsi:'" + ikinciYariBahsi + "',handikapBahsi:'" + handikapBahsi + "',cifteSans:'" + cifteSans + "',ilkYariCifteSans:'" + ilkYariCifteSans + "',paraIade:'" + paraIade + "',_05TG_AU:'" + _05TG_AU + "',_15TG_AU:'" + _15TG_AU + "',_25TG_AU:'" + _25TG_AU + "',_35TG_AU:'" + _35TG_AU + "',_05IY_AU:'" + _05IY_AU + "',_15IY_AU:'" + _15IY_AU + "',_25IY_AU:'" + _25IY_AU + "',hangiYariDahaCokGolOlur:'" + hangiYariDahaCokGolOlur + "',_05_2YAU:'" + _05_2YAU + "',_15_2YAU:'" + _15_2YAU + "',_25_2YAU:'" + _25_2YAU + "',ikiTakimdaGolAtarmi:'" + ikiTakimdaGolAtarmi + "',toplamGolTekCift:'" + toplamGolTekCift + "',ilkYariIkiTakimdaGolAtarmi:'" + ilkYariIkiTakimdaGolAtarmi + "',ilkYariTgTekCift:'" + ilkYariTgTekCift + "',ikinciYariTgTekCift:'" + ikinciYariTgTekCift + "',evSahibiHerIkiYariGolAtarmi:'" + evSahibiHerIkiYariGolAtarmi + ",deplasmanHerIkiYariGolAtarmi:'" + deplasmanHerIkiYariGolAtarmi + "'',herIkiDevre15AltOlur:'" + herIkiDevre15AltOlur + "',herIkiDevre15UstOlur:'" + herIkiDevre15UstOlur + "',ilkYariParaIade:'" + ilkYariParaIade + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error)
                {
                    errorHandling(xhr, status, error);
                }
            })
```

Error message : 
{"Message":"Geçersiz nesne geçirildi, \u0027:\u0027 veya \u0027}\u0027 bekleniyor. (709): {macBahsi:\u00271.60~3.90~6.00~\u0027,ilkYariBahsi:\u00272.05~2.25~5.50~\u0027,ikinciYariBahsi:\u00271.90~2.60~5.25~\u0027,handikapBahsi:\u00272.45~3.60~2.25~\u0027,cifteSans:\u00271.12~1.20~2.00~\u0027,ilkYariCifteSans:\u00271.12~1.45~1.55~\u0027,paraIade:\u00271.18~3.80~\u0027,_05TG_AU:\u00277.25~1.04~\u0027,_15TG_AU:\u00273.45~1.22~\u0027,_25TG_AU:\u00271.90~1.75~\u0027,_35TG_AU:\u00271.35~2.85~\u0027,_05IY_AU:\u00272.95~1.35~\u0027,_15IY_AU:\u00271.45~2.55~\u0027,_25IY_AU:\u00271.10~5.75~\u0027,hangiYariDahaCokGolOlur:\u00273.00~3.40~2.05~\u0027,_05_2YAU:\u00273.85~1.22~\u0027,_15_2YAU:\u00271.70~2.05~\u0027,_25_2YAU:\u00271.20~4.20~\u0027,ikiTakimdaGolAtarmi:\u00271.85~1.85~\u0027,toplamGolTekCift:\u00271.90~1.80~\u0027,ilkYariIkiTakimdaGolAtarmi:\u00274.35~1.16~\u0027,ilkYariTgTekCift:\u00272.05~1.70~\u0027,ikinciYariTgTekCift:\u00271.90~1.75~\u0027,evSahibiHerIkiYariGolAtarmi:\u00272.35~1.50~,deplasmanHerIkiYariGolAtarmi:\u00275.75~1.08~\u0027\u0027,herIkiDevre15AltOlur:\u00272.50~1.45~\u0027,herIkiDevre15UstOlur:\u00274.90~1.14~\u0027,ilkYariParaIade:\u00271.30~3.35~\u0027}","StackTrace":"   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   konum: System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid JSON format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530381/invalid-json-format)

Comment: This JSON format is not valid. See `UstOlur:\u00274.90~1.14~\u0027,ilkYariParaIade:\u00271.30~3.35~\u0027}` its missing quotation mark before ending `}`.